# How to Run the ios app on real device?

Tags: ios

I had an IPA would like to share with all other ios devices . This can be as ipa people can see through http://www.mediafire.com/download/97i15pp7qcxp4qa/AVPlayer%28v2.50%29.ipa . Can you give me a video tutorial or at least video images . thank you

Answer (score 0):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1669/beta-test-tutorial-how-to-host-a-beta-test-for-your-ios-app

Here you go, but it takes 5 seconds to google it.

Comment: I know this . ipa on all devices installed on different registers without UDID

Comment: What do you mean without UDID? Every iOS device has a UDID.

Comment: You can download ipa on the test on different devices without UDID registered

Comment: I want to be like that

Comment: UDID is short for Unique Device Identifier. Every iOS device has it. You don't need to register it. http://whatsmyudid.com/

Comment: By that I do not. I mean, you want to install on other devices . as far as I know ipa above contains " embedded.mobileprovision "

Comment: for more details you are not ?